# GParted doesn't start when I click the GParted icon

Tags: 12.04, gparted

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I have noticed that sometimes application doesn't start even after clicking the icon, what might be the problem. For example when I try to open GParted through the unity even after providing the correct password it doesn't show up but when I try to open through the terminal `sudo gparted` it opens up nicely after providing the password.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. It's complaining that GTK2 and GTK3 are installed at the same time.
(gpartedbin:3620): Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported

This looks like a software bug on Gparted's part as it should use the library it needs, not complain about libraries it doesn't need.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the desktop entry `/usr/share/applications/gparted.desktop` and substitute the entry `gparted-pkexec` with `gksudo gparted`. That should allow you to call the program from the Unity dash without problems.